# Magento + SOAP + Visual Studio C#

Tags: magento

I'm getting started with Magento SOAP and I've run into a brick wall in 5 minutes... I am following this guide http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/web_services/using_soap_api_in_c_sharp

Except when I add the reference ( `http://myurlremoved/store/index.php/api/?wsdl` - myurlremoved is my domain name) I get the following error:

```
The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://myurlremoved/store/index.php/api/?wsdl'.
The content type text/xml; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    name="Magento" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
<!--            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />-->
            <complexType name="FixedArray">
                <complexContent>
                    <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                        <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]" />
                    </restriction>
                </complexContent>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="call">
        <part name="sessionId'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I created a fresh Magento site on the same server and it connects fine. The Configuration > Magento Core API settings are the same on both sites. The store ID isn't encoded in the URL on the problematic site (noted as an issue in forums).

From what I understand, this might be because the Magento installation (which isn't working with SOAP) originated on a server without SOAP support. It has since been migrated to another server that does have support for it (which was confirmed by creating a blank site to test with).

How can I fix this?